# Echo post meta inside of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Wwhat am I missing that is causing this to not work?

```
$args = array('tag' => 'get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "solution_feed", true );');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no syntax error, which leads me to assume you want the result of that `get_post_meta` call and not store it as string literally (and i assume that's what you mean by `not work(ing)`). For that you'd have to remove the single qoutes

```
$args = array( 'tag' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "solution_feed", true ));
```